# "Element does not exist" message after editing hidden content with Google Optimise in interactive mode

Tags: google-optimize

I have just begun to use Google Optimize for one of my clients. I want to edit a form which pops up in a lightbox. To do this, I entered interactive mode and then selected the content I wanted to edit and it all appeared to work perfectly. However, after I saved, it then said that the element I selected does not exist. Is this due to the content not being within the source code of the main URL?